# Missing verb instead of Prepositional Phrase

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose I am reading some advertisement in the local newspaper because I am looking for a new house, and I find the following:

> ...spacious and ideal for big families, **with a view of** the Central Park. Call 00-12-345-6789.

What verb can be used to rewrite the phrase in bold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> ...spacious and ideal for big families, [**it overlooks**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/overlooks) Central Park.

As per Merriam-Webster:

> **2 b** : to rise above or afford a view of · the mountains that *overlook* the village